# How to show a DIV with some particular effect (growing, shrinking)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

A few months back I managed to show a div with some effect with the jquery `animate` function. It was like this:

```
.ui-dialog
{
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
background: red;

position: fixed;
left: 50%;
top: -100px;
margin-left: -100px;
}

var dialogue = $('.ui-dialog')

dialogue.animate({
left: "50%",
top: "50%",
marginLeft:  -dialogue.width()/2,
marginTop: -dialogue.height()/2
}, 1000);

<div class="ui-dialog">hi there</div>
```

The above code snippet worked, but now I have a different question. I want to show a `<div />` at the center of the page with some different effect. When the user clicks on a button then the `<div />` will appear like growing with opacity changes and when the user clicks on the "close" button then the `<div />` should disappear like shrinking with opacity.

Please go to this URL and check out how the div is showing. I want that exact effect to show and hide my div:

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/window/index.html

Please help me with code and concept.

---

**here i change**

```
var grower = $('.grower');

$('.click').click(function(){
grower.css({width:0, height:0, left:0, top:0});
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var left = windowWidth/2 - 150;
var top = windowHeight/2 - 150;
grower.css({left:windowWidth/2, top:windowHeight/2});
grower.animate({width:300, height:300, left:left, top:top},500);
});
```

Comment: I am not sure why you are not able to understand with the link itself. It's pretty neat and easy to understand. Where are you getting bobbed down

Answer (score 2):

First of all download the [Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/get-kendo-ui.aspx) and include it in your project.

Then in the page where you want to use this effect, link the scripts for Kendo and jquery.min.js.

Use the following code for the div

```
<p id="window">
    YourContent
</p>
```

Have this script tag added

```
<script>
    $("#window").kendoWindow({
       draggable: false,
       resizable: false,
       width: "500px",
       height: "300px",
       title: "Modal Window",
       modal: true,
       actions: ["Refresh", "Maximize", "Close"]
    });
</script>
```

And that's it. Nothing else is needed to be done :-)

Comment: i dont want to use kendoWindow rather need to achieve this using jquery and div. can u help.

Comment: why do you want to reinvent the wheel?. Even if you want to, then read kendo source script, it offers everything :-)

Answer (score 1):

consider `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods

or `.animate({opacity: 0})` and `.animate({opacity: 1})`

**UPDATE**: Just made a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qiao/L9bRR

Comment: can u provide me sample code. have u check the url what kind of effect i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're actually using jQuery UI. If it's so, then you can use any effect bundled in the animation module (like "fade"). In the other hand, you can try the following code:

```
// To fade in growing...
$('#div').animate({
  opacity : 1,
  height  : 300, // You desired height.
  width   : 400
});

// To fade out shrinking...
$('#div').animate({
  opacity : 1,
  height  : 0,
  width   : 0
});
```

**Note**, before the fade in, your `<div />`'s height & width should be both 0, to *see* the effect.

Comment: Use `hide` and `show` for the height and width instead of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it: http://jsfiddle.net/Sj4eG/3/

You need to position the animated div with `position:absolute`. When the div that triggers the animation is clicked, we grab the current height and width of the window to figure out the initial starting position for the growing div as well as the position it should animate to.

HTML

```
<div class="click">Click here</div>
<div class="grower"></div>
```

CSS

```
.click {background:#ccc; border:1px solid black; padding:10px; display:inline-block}
.grower {width:0; height:0; background:red; position:absolute; top:150px; left:150px}
```

JS

var grower = $('.grower');

```
$('.click').click(function(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var left = windowWidth/2 - 150;
    var top = windowHeight/2 - 150;
    grower.css({left:windowWidth/2, top:windowHeight/2});
    grower.animate({width:300, height:300, left:left, top:top},500);
});
```

Comment: ur code works but i need grower div should appear at center of page and it should not be in any another div. please modify accordingly possible. thanks

Comment: thanks for ur effort but the code is not tested properly. just see if u click twice on click here button. i need two button one for showing div with growing effect and another button to hide with reverse effect. if user click on click here button then u should first clear the div and regenerate the div with effect and same way when user will click on hide button then check it is hidden already or not if not then hide it. please change the code accordingly if possible. i change ur code a bit but things did not work properly. u will find the change code at ur post end.

Comment: Thomas, this forum isn't for people to do everything for you. You should be able to figure out how to close the div yourself based on the code I provided. If what you tried isn't working, post a link to a fiddle so that I can see what you've tried.

Comment: i change ur code and now it is working. i edit my post to have the change...u can also have a look. thanks

Comment: So do you still have a question? Here's an example of it closing back down since I can't tell if you figured that out yet: http://jsfiddle.net/Sj4eG/8/ just click the button a second time and the red square will disappear.